# Как в Postgresql сделать запрос помесячно в разрезе последних 12 месяцев?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Подскажите пожалуйста по вопросу :

У меня есть SQL запрос, формирующий результат (отчет "о среднем времени ответа сотрудника") .

Отчет собирает в данный момент статистику только за текущий месяц.

Как мне модифицировать запрос так, чтобы он выдавал результат помесячно в разрезе последних 12 месяцев?

( Т.е результат времени за апрель 2023, март  2023, февраль 2023, январь 2023, декабрь 2022 и т.д)

Любая помощь важна ! Спасибо!

```
with My_request as

(select jiraissue.pkey , min(age(jiraaction.created, jiraissue.created))as first_time_response -- Время первого ответа
from jiraaction 
inner join jiraissue on jiraaction.issueid = jiraissue.id 
where jiraissue.pkey like '%TPAGENT-%'
and (jiraissue.created between (date_trunc('month', now())::date ) and now()::date) --Тикеты созданные за текущий месяц  и прокомментированные автором
group by jiraissue.pkey
order by first_time_response asc)

select avg(sum_first_t_r) as avg_time_response, now() as date_column  --  Среднее время ответа в минутах
from (select pkey, (sum(first_time_response)) as sum_first_t_r from My_request group by pkey) as table_avg_time_response
```

Текущий вывод в БД:

| avg_time_response | date_column |
| --- | --- |
| 00:51:41.634325 | 2023-04-24 14:47:19 |